# Is having double bachelor's disadvantageous in masters admissions?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, europe

I am looking to apply for masters this year. I've previously changed universities after studying data science to physics. If I would finish my data science bachelor's would that affect my application positively/negatively?

Comment: A masters in which discipline?  Which country?

Comment: In physics, somewhere in Europe. Currently thinking of UK, France and Germany.

Answer (score 2):

A bachelors in data science would not harm your application for a masters in physics.  It might be slightly helpful.

However, be ready to answer the question:  Why did you get this extra bachelors?  Data science is not really a discipline at this point in time, in the sense that it does not have a well defined methodology.  If you think this degree creates value, you need to explain that value.

Comment: Many would disagree about your conclusion that Data Science is not a discipline, and others will disagree with the definition that a discipline must have a well established methodology.